# React useState updates on click ahead of the desired click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating 50 buttons which on click should set the useState value to the current button number (array index+1).
But I realized that I have to click a button twice to get the current value (array index+1). The first click always gets the previously clicked button value. e.g. When I clicked button 1 for the first time, I get nothing, when I clicked button 2 I get 1, when I clicked button 3 I get 2. Thank you.

Here is the code

```
 const [theValue, setTheValue] = useState({first: 1});
 const [disableNext, setDisableNext] = useState(false);
 const [disablePrev, setDisablePrev] = useState(true);

             <div className="flex flex-row">
            {disablePrev ? <div className="flex flex-1 justify-start">
<button type="button" className="btn bg-gray-300 text-gray-400 m-10" disabled>Previous</button></div> 
: <div className="flex flex-1 justify-start">
<button type="button" className="btn bg-jamb-light-green text-white m-10 hover:bg-green-400" onClick={prevButton}>Previous</button></div>}
            
        {disableNext ? <div className="flex flex-1 justify-end">
<button type="button" className="btn bg-gray-300 text-gray-400 m-10" disabled>Next</button></div>
 : <div className="flex flex-1 justify-end">
<button type="button" className="btn bg-jamb-light-green text-white m-10 hover:bg-green-400" onClick={nextButton}>Next</button></div> }   
        </div>
<div>
            {[...Array(50)].map((item, index) => {
                return (
                        <button key={index}  className={(index+1 === theValue.first) ? "w-10 h-10 p-2 m-0.5 rounded-full bg-green-500 text-white" : "w-10 p-2 m-0.5 rounded-full bg-red-300 hover:bg-green-400 hover:text-white"}
                         onClick={
                            () => {
                             if(theValue.first === 1){
                             setDisablePrev(true);                                    
                             }else if((theValue.first > 1) && (theValue.first < 49)){
                             setDisablePrev(false);
                                                           }
                             if(theValue.first === 50){
                               setDisableNext(true);
                             }else if(theValue.first < 50 && theValue.first > 1){
                             setDisableNext(false);                                    
                             }
                             setTheValue({...theValue, first: index+1})
                        }
                    }>{index+1}</button>
                    
                )
            })}
        </div>
```

Comment: Since both `first` and `index` are used to render the button (to some degree) try `key={index+'-'+theValue.first}` as the key to avoid potentially passing the wrong state object to the closures

Comment: Okay thanks. I will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the state is set on the next render. To update the state by 1 you could do:

```js
 const [theValue, setTheValue] = useState({first: 1});


 <div>
   {[...Array(50)].map((item) =>(
         <button key={index} className={(index+1 === theValue.first) ? "w-10 h-10 p-2 m-0.5 rounded-full bg-green-500 text-white" : "w-10 p-2 m-0.5 rounded-full bg-red-300 hover:bg-green-400 hover:text-white"}
           onClick={
            () => {
              setTheValue(currentStateValue => {...currentStateValue, first: currentStateValue.first+1})
            }
         }>{index+1}</button>   
      )
  )}
 </div>
```

Comment: It did not work. I get syntax error in VS. And the ```index``` of ```map``` is what sets the desired value between 1 to the length of the array (50). I am creating 50 buttons which on click should set the useState value to the clicked button number (array index number). The issue I am having is I have to click a button twice to get the current value. The first click always gets the previously clicked button value. e.g. When I clicked button 1 for the first time, I get nothing, when I clicked button 2 I get 1, when I clicked button 3 I get 2. Thank you.

Comment: Oh i see I didn't understood your question properly. Will update my answer asap

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is typo in your second if condition, `theValue.firts`. Coming to your issue, when you update a state inside a function, the updated state is not immediately accessible inside the same function. You only have access to the previous state value. So let's say, the current state value is `9` and when you click button number `10`, you are updating the state value to `10` and at the same time console logging the value of `theValue.first` whose value is still `9` currently since it doesn't have access to the updated state value of `10`. Now if you click the same button number again, it will display `10` but it doesn't mean it is the updated state value, it is the value of state that you previously set(which is `10`) when you clicked the button. That's what is going on there. However, you will be able to access the latest updated state value inside the render div inside the paragraph as I have added for demo below. Going with your question, the state value is updated correctly. It's just that console logging from the same function makes you feel otherwise.

```js
const [theValue, setTheValue] = useState({
  first: 1
});


<div> {
    [...Array(50)].map((item, index) => {
      return ( <
        button key = {
          index
        }
        className = {
          (index + 1 === theValue.first) ? "w-10 h-10 p-2 m-0.5 rounded-full bg-green-500 text-white" : "w-10 p-2 m-0.5 rounded-full bg-red-300 hover:bg-green-400 hover:text-white"
        }
        onClick = {
          () => {
            if (theValue.first === 1) {
              console.log(theValue.first);

            } else if (theValue.first > 1) {

              console.log(theValue.first);
            }
            if (theValue.first === 50) {
              console.log(theValue.first);

            } else if (theValue.first < 50) {
              console.log(theValue.first);

            }
            setTheValue({ ...theValue,
              first: index + 1
            })
          }
        } > {
          index + 1
        } < /button>

      )
    })
  } 
  
  <p>{theValue.first}</p> // access to updated state value
  </div>
```

Comment: I've corrected the typo, thanks. What you said was exactly what happening, the current value was registered correctly just not available for the function immediately. But that was my problem. You see, I want to disable a `Prev` button whenever the `theValue.first === 1` and enable it when the value is > 1 and < 49, and also disable 'Next` button whenever `theValue.first === 50` and enable it when the value is less than 50. If I can't get the current value immediately on click, I don't think I will be able to achieve that, at least not the way I am trying to do it.

Comment: I don't know how you are trying to disable the button, but I would suggest you check the condition then and there while assigning the classname since you will have access to the latest updated state value if you do so, and disable the button with css `pointer-events:none` on the classname you assign when disable conditions are met. And yes, I agree with you that it would be impossible to achieve that from within the onclick callback.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have edited the original question and incorporated the buttons in the `code`. I am using tailwind.css framework for CSS functionality.